# How do you send a docusign envelope later after it is created using PHP sdk

Tags: php, docusignapi

I'm trying to send an envelope after it is created because I'm adding a redirect url to recipients view.

I am unable to find a way to send the envelope except at createEnvelope function which depends on `$envelop_definition->setStatus("sent")`;

I am using DocuSign [PHP sdk](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client)

```
$envelop_definition = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeDefinition();
$envelop_definition->setEmailSubject($subject);
$envelop_definition->setTemplateId($templateid);
$envelop_definition->setTemplateRoles($templateRoles);
//$envelop_definition->setStatus("sent");

$options = new \DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi\CreateEnvelopeOptions();
$options->setCdseMode(null);
$options->setMergeRolesOnDraft(null);

// create and send the envelope (aka signature request)
$envelop_summary = $envelopeApi->createEnvelope($accountId, $envelop_definition, $options);
$envelop_summary = json_decode($envelop_summary);
if(!empty($envelop_summary)){
// set the returnURL
$envelope_id = $envelop_summary->envelopeId;
$url = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/docusign/helloworld.html?envelope_id=' . $envelope_id;

foreach ($recipients->getSigners() as $recipient) {
     $recipient_view_request = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\RecipientViewRequest();
     // set where the recipient is re-directed once they are done signing
     recipient_view_request->setReturnUrl($url);
}
```

Comment: $recipients = $envelopeApi->listRecipients($accountId, $envelope_id);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you just need to call the [Envelopes: update](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/update/) API with the envelope `status` set to `sent`.  The raw API request looks like:

```
PUT /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}

{
    "status": "sent"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign PHP SDK users:

```
$envelopeApi->update($accountId, $envelope_id, json_encode(['status' => 'sent']));
```